# Can Aluffi's Algebra Chapter 0 act as a starting point for learning abstract and (advanced) linear algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

I am a first year undergraduate student majoring in mathematics. Due to the travel ban caused by the Covid-19 outbreak, I am suspending my studies from my uni in the second half of the year (so I have roughly 6-7 months of free time from now). I am planning to teach myself some abstract algebra as well as advanced linear algebra during the break.

More specifically, I am looking for a thorough introduction (and hopefully as general as possible while still being accessible for undergrad) to the basic algebraic objects like groups, rings, fields and vector spaces. The book I am considering to use is Aluffi's *Algebra: Chapter 0*. This is because the book seems quite comprehensive and self-contained (at least by looking from its table of contents), and the fact that Aluffi introduces categories along the way is also a huge attraction to me that most textbooks don't have.

The thing is, by far I have taken first-year linear algebra, but I have never studied abstract algebra in a systematic manner. I have seen quite a few comments/reviews saying that Aluffi's book is for a **second** exposure to modern algebra.

So, speaking of my situation, may I ask if *Algebra: Chapter 0* can be used as the first book for self-studying abstract algebra (& advanced linear algebra)? And in particular, what would be the pros and cons in doing so?

Any recommendations on other options that may be better than Aluffi's for my situation are also heartily welcomed.

Comment: Hi J-A-S, I won't write an answer to this question, because I'm not really familiar with Aluffi's book. But based on the preface and table of contents, I'd say I agree with you that it looks like a reasonable book to start with. A couple of other books I *know* are good are the ones by Artin and Jacobson. There will be a little bit of repetition of linear algebra for you in Artin, but the way it's mixed with group theory means much of the material on linear algebra will be new. Jacobson is at a higher level of difficulty, but for capable students it's an excellent introduction to algebra.

Comment: The exercises in Artin are perhaps on the easy side. Good exercises can be found in *Algebra* by Godement. I like this book (apart from the chapter on logic), but unfortunately it stops short of important topics like Galois theory and group representations. Godement and Artin have in common that they teach abstract algebra and linear algebra together. Jacobson assumes you know a bit about determinants in the early chapters, but treats them properly later in the book. A really important point is that the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a principal ideal domain...

Comment: (Chapter 14 in Artin, Chapter 3 in Jacobson, Chapter VI in Aluffi) has really important applications to linear algebra (clarifying much of the theory surrounding minimal and characteristic polynomials, Jordan and rational canonical forms, and much else). This is one place where studying abstract algebra along with linear algebra has huge advantages. Again, this topic is left out of Godement's book, unfortunately.

Comment: We used Aluffi in my first year graduate algebra courses, and I had a miserable time. I then discovered Dummit and Foote, and the difference between the books was shocking. I would steer clear of Aluffi and go with D&F.

Comment: @Anonymous Thank you very much! I'll check them out! I also noticed that the books by Herstein seem to be good references as well :)

Comment: @Junglemath Thanks! I will definitely keep D&F around. And actually, I just had a miserable time with Aluffi's book as well in the past few days haha. I'm not saying Aluffi's book is bad, and I can see that he keeps a very good focus on the significant subtleties of algebra while still trying to be self-contained. But I think Aluffi's book is self-contained in a sense that he assumes that the reader already knows most of what he is saying in the first place...